# C: Adding data to structure using linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm new to c and learning about linked lists, I decided to create a library manager to manage my books using linked list but it doesn't seem to be saving the data to the structure using linked list. When someone tries to add a new book the function hits the checkID function to see if the book with the same id already exists but when i do a display information nothing seems to exists in the structure.

```
void addBook()
{
    int bookId;
    BOOK *head = NULL, *temp;
    temp = (BOOK*) malloc(sizeof(BOOK));

    printf("\n Enter Book Details\n");
    printf("Enter book ISBN: ");
    scanf("%d", &bookId);
    int bInd = checkID(bookId);
    if (bInd == 0)
    {
        printf("Enter book title: ");
        scanf("%s", &temp->chTitle);
        printf("Enter book type (eg. magazine, novel): ");
        scanf("%s", &temp->chType);
        printf("Enter book publisher (eg. UTA): ");
        scanf("%s", &temp->chPublisher);
        printf("Enter book's number of pages: ");
        scanf("%d", &temp->nPages);
        printf("Enter book's price: ");
        scanf("%f", &temp->nPrice);
        printf("Enter year published: ");
        scanf("%d", &temp->nPubYear);
        //temp->next=NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
        else{
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
        }
        //BOOK[count].nStatus = IN;
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nSorry another book with that id: Try again!\n" );
        addBookFunction();
    }
}

int checkID(int t)
{
    BOOK *head;
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        if (head->nID == t)
            return 1;
        head = head->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `head` has been requested that it is a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry ! It's normal ! You are creating a new book library each time you add a book ! :)

At your place, an easy way to solve it would be to pass your "Library collection of book" to your AddBook method :

```
void addBook(BOOK *libraryBooks)
int checkID(BOOK *libraryBooks, int t)
```

Then remove your variable declaration 'head'. Change all 'head' by 'libraryBooks' and pass the variable to checkID.

Above this function you'll have to manage your library.

Answer (score 0):

`checkID()` and `addBook()` should probably both accept the head of your linked list as an additional parameter.  The `head` pointer that iterates through your linked list in `checkID()` looks like it's getting used before it's initialized with a proper value.  It may just be lucky happenstance that you haven't hit a null pointer exception already.